# How to find SQL Query Plan (Performance\Optimization) using visual studio IDE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, query-optimization, sqlperformance

How to find SQL Query Plan (Performance\Optimization) using visual studio IDE?

Comment: should be under the Query menu..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step1 :**

Add connection from Tools menu

**Step2:**
click new query and select include actual execution plan as highlighted below in image

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To view the execution plan for a query

1. Open Visual Studio 2010
2. On the Data menu, select the Transact-SQL editor and connect.
3. If there is no query in the query pane, open a saved query or create a new query.
4. Right-click the editor, and then click Display Estimated Execution Plan.
5. A graphical representation of the execution plan is displayed. You can position the pointer over graphical elements to reveal additional execution plan information.
6. On the Transact-SQL Editor toolbar, click Execute SQL.